# mounting ntfs usb drive in linux (with permissioning)

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, drive

I'm trying to mount an external harddrive in linux.
I added the following line in /etc/fstab

```
/dev/sdf1               /path/to/my/mount      ntfs    defaults,umask=022      0 0
```

and then do

```
sudo mount -a
```

Everything mounts fine (shows up in df, etc.) but after creating folders / files in the drive,  I can't "chown" them. It's all stuck as root.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I don't think any of the NTFS implementations support Linux permissions on NTFS volumes.  Everything is exposed as belonging to a single user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NTFS permissions and *nix permissions don't mix well. If you want full *nix permissions on the external drive, reformat it to ext2/3 or your favorite non-Windows filesystem.